# Postgresql delete without DELETE CASCADE

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-delete, cascade

I have some rows to delete from a table:

```sql
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE id=1
```

However the row with id=1 is referenced in `another_table` as a foreign key.

In an ideal world, it would cascade and also delete the related entry in `another_table`. However the foreign key wasn't references as cascade delete and has null=False. So deleting the element with id=1 in my_table cannot be achieved with the query from above because it would cause an integrity error in `another_table`.

Is there something like:

```sql
DELETE CASCADE FROM my_table WHERE id=1
```

Which deletes related foreign keys?

Alternatively is there another way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: The person(s) who designed the db decided to have it this way, perhaps to avoid accidental cascade effects. I.e. you have to delete data in the right order.

Comment: You need to delete the row from the referencing table first (`another_table`). `ON DELETE CASCADE` or other referential integrity constraints are set in the referencing table's definition.

Comment: There is an extension that provides a function to do that: https://github.com/trlorenz/PG-recursively_delete (I have never used it though)

Comment: Basically we are using `sqlalchemy` which has a ORM and a cascade property for it which is not implemented corrently (i.e. when you delete an entry, it makes several other queries to delete the foreign keys). We want to do it in one query as its becoming slow.